# Problem with underscore character

Tags: characters

I'm writing my thesis in latex, and I've included some figures and some labels with character `_` in the name. Now that i'm adding `\listoffigures`, i find some errors with `missing $ inserted`.

How can I solve this problem and add my list of figures, without changing every underscore character?

EDIT

Problem is soved without this figure:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \subfigure[$\mathrm{RMSE}$]
   {
   \label{fig:cfrcovar1}
    \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{Immagini/Confronto_metodi_covar.png}   
   }
    \subfigure[Stime $\hat{\beta}$]
   {
   \label{fig:cfrcovar2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{Immagini/Confronto_metodi_beta.png}
   }
    \caption{Confronto tra i metodi, caso con covariate}
    \label{fig:cfrcovar}
\end{figure}
```

something wrong about it?

Comment: Figure *captions* with `_` are not okay. Figure *file* names with `_` are okay. Labels with `_` are also okay.

Comment: My underscore characters are all in file/folder names and labels, not in captions. So what is the problem? Maybe some other characters?

Comment: @Darko: You should show us a small example which fails, everything else would be doing wild guessing around

Comment: Maybe. It's all just guess-work. Before moving on, delete all `.aux`, `.toc`, `.lof` and `.lot` files and recompile a couple of times. If the problem persists, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so we can replicate the problem.

Comment: i've edited the figure with the error

Comment: I suspect some `\caption[a_x]{foo}` with no math mode in the optional argument of `\caption`, which compiles in the first run, but then fails when `\listoffigures` comes into action

Comment: Not sure, but `\hat` can be funny sometimes. Perhaps `\protect` it...

Comment: Please provide a *compilable* example --  not just some code snippets -- that produces the error you would like to fix. I am not able to generate a problem if I use the `article` document class, load the `subfigure` package in the preamble, and insert the instruction `\listoffigures` after `\begin{document}`. It may be your document class and/or one or more packages that you load that's causing the problem, rather than the code you've posted so far.

Comment: Here you can find a compilable example, that produced me the error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47720440/Error.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to the line

```
\caption{Per alcuni istanti di tempo, funzione test $f(\underline p,t)$ reale, dati 
simulati, stime ottenute rispettivamente con GAMM con soap film smoothing, GAMM con thin 
plate splines e stima con STR-PDE nel caso con covariata.}
```

First of all, you should write `\underline{p}` and not `\underline p` since `\underline` takes an argument.

Moreover, since you are using it in a `\caption` it needs to be `\protect`ed, otherwise its meaning is expanded in the `.lof` file.

In other words, you have to write

```
$f(\protect\underline{p},t)$
```

instead of

```
$f(\underline p,t)$
```